# How to change arrow to \Rightarrow in psmatrix?

Tags: arrows, psmatrix

I would like to change arrow to `\Rightarrow` in `psmatrix`, how can I do that? Actually I do not need the arrows to be so long. Because G, H, R are statements, I just want to show the imply relations.

code that is not `\Rightarrow` but `\rightarrow` is as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{psmatrix}
          &       $ G        &   \\
$H$     &                   & $R $ 
\psset{arrows=->,arrowscale=2,labelsep=3pt,nodesep=3pt}
\ncline{2,1}{1,2}
\ncline{1,2}{2,3}
\ncline{2,1}{2,3}

\end{psmatrix}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by presenting a clear example of what you're after exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean. I use the `pst-poly` package; it loads `pst-node` and `pstricks`. To change its size, just change the value of `unit`.

The solution is *almost* as simple as possible. Almost, because there seems to be a small bug in pst-poly – unless I missed something: I have to draw an equilateral triangle with invisible sides, and setting`linewidth=0pt` still produces very thin lines at the three angles.  A work around consists in setting also `linestyle=dotted` ( `linestyle=none` doesn't work).

```
    \documentclass[12pt,leqno, pdf]{article}
    \usepackage{pst-poly}
    \newcommand*\implies[2]{\ncline[linewidth = 0pt]{#1}{#2} \ncput*[nrot=:U]{\ensuremath{\Rightarrow}}}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{pspicture}
    \psset{unit = 0.6cm, linewidth = 0pt, linestyle  = dotted}%
    \PstTriangle[PolyName = A]
    \implies{A2}{A1}\implies{A1}{A3}\implies{A2}{A3}
    \rput(A1){G}\rput(A2){H}\rput(A3){R}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard, when I run it, there is an error: file ended while scanning use of \pst@@picture. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I've just tested with a copy of the code (a wrong version might have been uploaded by error) and I have no problem. Are you sure you copied *all* code (it happens that one forgets to select a backslash, a brace…). It might be an explanation.

Comment: still does not work for me, no idea why. I might try to use another computer to test later.

Comment: Did you think of launching pdflatex with `--enable-write18` if you're under MiKTeX, `--shell-escape` if you're under TeX Live or MacTeX. You also can try the `latex->dvi->dvips` way (it happens that the direct pdf way doesn't work— though not with such a simple code).  Also check you have the latest version of pstricks and pst-node.